# Creating a table of results over multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I am using a large dataset that contains multiple variables that contain similar information. The variables range from PR1 through PR25. Each contains information regarding a procedure code. in short the dataframe looks like this:

```
Obs  PR1   PR2    PR3
1    527   1422   222
2    1600  527    569 
3    341   222    341 
4    222   569    1422
5    569   341    1660
```

Where PR1 through PR25 values are factors.

I am looking for a way to make a table of information across all of these variables. For instance, I would like to make a table that shows a count of total number of value "527" for PR1:PR25. I would like to do this for multiple values of interest.

For instance

```
PR   Tot
#222  3
#341  3
#527  2
#569  3
#1600 1
#1660 1
```

However, I only want to retrieve the frequency for a very specific set of values such as only extracting the frequency of `527` or `1600`.

I have initially tried using a simple function like `length(which(PR1=="527"))`, which works but is tedious.

I used the method suggested by Soren using:

```
library(plyr)
all_codes <- data.frame(codes=unlist(lapply(df,levels),use.names=F))
result <- ddply(all_codes,.(codes),summarize,count=length(codes))
result[which(result$codes %in% c("527", "5251", "5252", "5253", "5259", 
"526", "521", "529", "8512", "8521", "344", "854", "8523", "8541", "8546", 
"8542", "8547" , "8544", "8545", "8543", "639", 
"064","065","063","0650","0651", "0652", "062", "066", "4040", "4041", 
"4042", "0721", "0712","0701", "0702", "070", "0741", "435","436", "4399", 
"439", "438", "437", "4381", "4391", "4342", "5122", "5121", "5124", "5123", 
"518", "519", "503", "5022", "5012")),]
```

And got the following output (abbreviated):

```
        codes count
 92     062     5
 95     064     8
 96    0650     2
 769    526     8
 770    527     8
```

However, I had a feeling that was incorrect. When I checked it against the output from `sapply(df, function(PR1) length(which(PR1 == "527")))`
I get the following:

```
PR1  PR2  PR3  PR4  PR5  PR6  PR7  PR8  ... 
1152   36    6    1    2    1    1    1
```

Which is the correct number of "527" cases in the dataframe. Any suggestions why the first method is giving incorrect sums of factor levels?

Thanks for any help, and let me know if I can provide more info

Comment: OK I updated the question to be more explicit about the dataframe and desired output. I don't know that the first answer would get me to the output desired.

Comment: Hi Tim, apologies if the response may have been a bit off.  Looking it over, it may be an issue of how the factor is rendering levels versus labels in the underlying dataset.  Perhaps it's not the levels() you're after, but simply a direct as.character() -- does data.frame(codes=unlist(lapply(df,as.character),use.names=F)) get what you're after?

Comment: Hi Soren, that worked! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` or `lapply()` function to get count of a some value over all columns.

Create data frame `df`

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:4, B = c(4,4,4,4), C = c(2,3,4,4), D = 9:12)
df
#   A B C  D
# 1 1 4 2  9
# 2 2 4 3 10
# 3 3 4 4 11
# 4 4 4 4 12
```

Frequency of value "4" in each column A, B, C, and D using `sapply()` function

```
sapply(df, function(x) length(which(x == 4)))
A B C D 
1 4 2 0
```

Frequency of value "4" in each column A, B, C, and D using `lapply()` function

```
lapply(df, function(x) length(which(x == 4)))
# $A
# [1] 1

# $B
# [1] 4

# $C
# [1] 2

# $D
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following takes your example and returns an output that may be generalized across all 25 columns.  The "plyr" library is used to create the aggregated counts

Scripted as follows:

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(PR1=c("527","1600","341","222","569"),PR2=c("1422","527","222","569","341"),PR3=c("222","569","341","1422","1660"),stringsAsFactors = T)
all_codes <- data.frame(codes=unlist(lapply(df,levels),use.names=F))
result <- ddply(all_codes,.(codes),summarize,count=length(codes))  
result[which(result$codes %in% c('527','222')),]
```

Explained as follows:

Create the data frame as specified above.  As OP noted values are factors, stringsAsFactors is set to TRUE

```
df <- data.frame(
     PR1=c("527","1600","341","222","569"),
     PR2=c("1422","527","222","569","341"),
     PR3=c("222","569","341","1422","1660"),
     stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Reviewing results of df

```
df
```

`PR1  PR2  PR3
1  527 1422  222
2 1600  527  569
3  341  222  341
4  222  569 1422
5  569  341 1660`

As OP asks to combine all the codes across PR1:PR25 a these are unified into a single list by using lapply to loop across all the columns.   However, as these are factors -- and it seems that the interest in the in the *level* value of the factor and not its underlying numeric representation, lapply(df,levels) returns these values.   To merge into a single list PR1:PR25 it's simply unlist() and since the column names are seemingly not useful in this case, use.names is set to FALSE.   Finally, a data.frame is created with the single column called codes, which is later fed into the ddply() function to get the counts.

```
all_codes <- data.frame(codes=unlist(lapply(df,levels),use.names=F))

all_codes
```

`codes
1   1600
2    222
3    341
4    527
5    569
6   1422
7    222
8    341
9    527
10   569
11  1422
12  1660
13   222
14   341
15   569`

Uisng ddply() to split() the data.frame on df$codes value and then take the length() of each vector returned by split in ddply()

```
result <- ddply(all_codes,.(codes),summarize,count=length(codes))
result
```

Reviewing the result gives the PR1:PR25 aggregated count of all the level values of each factor in the original data.frame

`codes count
1  1422     2
2  1600     1
3  1660     1
4   222     3
5   341     3
6   527     2
7   569     3`

And since we're only interested in specific values (527 given in OP, but here two values of interest are exemplified, 527 and 222:

```
result[which(result$codes %in% c('527','222')),]
```

`codes count
4   222     3
6   527     2`

Comment: Thanks for the input, can you clarify the issue I describe above?